# Reading a txt file using Classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, text, java-7

I'm struggling with creating my class file right now, I have a txt file that has the team name followed by 20 batting averages.

UPDATE:
I believe that i have read the team name off the txt file now what is it that i am missing to read the batting averages

Txt file :

```
Tars 
0.592
0.427
0.194
0.445
0.127
0.483
0.352
0.190
0.335
0.207
0.116
0.387
0.243
0.225
0.401
0.382
0.556
0.319
0.475
0.279
```

This is my code so far If you have input on what is missing or can be done different please help:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BaseballStats {

private String fileName;
private String teamName;
private double [] battingAverage;


public BaseballStats ( String fileName )
{
this.fileName = fileName;
boolean firstLine = true;
Scanner input = new Scanner(fileName);
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
String line = input.nextLine();
if (firstLine) 
{
  setTeamName (line);
  firstLine = false;
  continue;
}
   int i=0;
     while(input.hasNext())
     {
     battingAverage[i] = input.nextDouble();
    i++;      
}
}
public String getTeamName( )
{
 return teamName;
}

public void setTeamName( String newTeamName )
{
teamName=newTeamName;
}

public double findMaxAverage( )
{
double max =battingAverage[0];
for ( int i =1; i < battingAverage.length; i++)
    {
  if(battingAverage[i] >max)
    max= battingAverage[i];
}
return max;
}
public double findMinAverage( )
{
double min =battingAverage[0];
for ( int i =1; i < battingAverage.length; i++)
{
  if(battingAverage[i] < min)
    min= battingAverage[i];
}
return min;
}    
public double spread( )
{
//returns the difference between the highest and lowest batting averages
}
public int goodPlayers( )
{     
  //returns the number of players with an average higher than .300
}
 public String toString( )
 {  
  // returns a String containing the team name followed by all the batting averages         formatted to three decimal places.
 }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing almost every part of the code. You should read a tutorial on how to do this sort of thing in general, and then ask us if you have a problem with one particular part of it.

Comment: i know im missing every part of the code, im wanting help on how to create a class file to read the team name and batting averages, once i have that i will be able to do the rest of the code on my own.

Comment: Isn't this your question as well, which is asking the same thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365379/creating-a-constructor-to-read-a-txt-file

Comment: yes you're right my apologies for posting again, i was needing more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint.

For the max and min averages you will need a class variable to hold this values.

Also look at using Math.min and Math.max

**Update**
To read the file create a new method `public void readFile () {...}`

In here

```
 boolean firstLine = true;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(<file>));
 while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    if (firstLine) {
      setTeamName (line);
      firstLine = false;
      continue;
    }

    // convert line to Double
    // perform Math
}
```

Comment: i understand how to do that, how do i get the numbers off the txt file so i can do that.

Comment: i think im placing it in the wrong spot i keep getting errors.

Comment: also couldnt i just do while(scan.hasNext()) 
{
    scan.nextLine();
  
    String teamName= scan.next();

Comment: I updated the code can you check to see if that seems right?

Comment: No.  Firstly I said create a new method (you do not want your constructor to potentially throw an Exception).  Secondly compare my while loop with your.  I use a boolean so that the teamName is only set for the first line.

Comment: on our assigment it says: "You can assume the first item in the file is the team name " so wouldnt a boolean not be neccesary?

Comment: No, because you are looping, on the second and third loop, how would you know it was not the first loop?  That's right use a boolean or a counter.

Comment: ok can you check my code again, thanks for the help

Comment: Getting there.  If you indent your code you will notice that your are instantiation your battingAverage  in your loop.  You want to do this before your loop.  In you loop, you want to insert into the battingAverage array.  Maybe you need a counter after all.

Comment: Thanks, I dont think i understand what you mean though. looking through my text book i have found nothing about counters

Comment: Is there a way i can talk to you outside of here?

Comment: By counter I mean an int that you increment (as you have done).  You code looks good.  Does it work?  If not, then like the rest of us developers, you will need to debug it.  Use an IDE like eclipse and you wil be fine.

Comment: I haveen't created the BaseballStatsClient yet to test it because i am complexly lost on how to get that started

Comment: i have now ran tests and the values outputted are incorrect?

Comment: at least it runs.  I see you have moved this onto a new question (good idea)

Comment: yes thanks for your help, i just cant figure out how to read the text file

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(<file>));
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = input.nextLine();
   ....
}
```

to read lines of text from the file.

Comment: Where does it go, in the public BaseballStats(String Filename?